# What is the fastest way of finding EAN Number doublettes in a SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

In SQL I have an `EanTbl (EAN varchar(13) (PK), ProductID int)` with millions of EAN barcode numbers as string. Many of which are in reality the same but written differently, i.e. with **one or more leading zeros**. One ProductID can be assigned to many EAN Barcodes numbers. *(historically grown, I would have created the EAN column as Long from the beginning)*

From now on, when a EAN barcode is inserted, I want to avoid the creation of additional doublettes by checking if an already existing EAN matches the new one.

Example EanTbl:

```
        EAN | ProductID
==========================
   123456789| 987           \
  0123456789| 987           - In reality the same EAN
 00123456789| 987           /
```

Now, when a user Input wants me to insert a new value of for instance `000123456789` I now want the most efficient query possible in T-SQL to discover that there are already matching EAN Barcodes assigned to this ProductID.

I already tried the different flavours of CONVERT() but as you can imagine the performance is horrible. This check needs to happens several hundreds times a minute on a table with 50+ millions of rows.

Thanks in advance for the suggestions.

Comment: Dropped C# and .NET tags: if you are round tripping across the network it is not going to be quick.

Comment: Do you know the maximum number of leading zeroes? If so you could chain where's `SELECT * WHERE EAN = '00number' AND EAN = '0number'` and properly index EAN

Comment: Two thoughts: 1. computed column without the leading zeros, 2. any other approach for that kind of performance solution will pre-calculate the canonical value for the searching. And of course index the canonical form.

Comment: Why is `ProductID` not unique? Or is it possible to have more `EAN` Codes for one `ProductID`?

Comment: @CeOnSql yes, that is possible.

Comment: As far as I know `EAN` is supposed to have a length of either 8 or 13. You should not be keeping them like you are atm. Instead, you should have a different column eg. add_date, on which you could later decide which was first added. Why would you be having "the-same-but-different" EANs for each product??

Comment: It has grown historically like that since the early 2000's, not my fault :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestions. In the Long term I will reorganize the table as most of you suggested but for the moment I found the fastest way to do what I want is something like that:

```
SELECT EanCode, ProductID 
FROM EanCodes 
WHERE EanCode = @ean 
    OR EanCode = '0'+@ean 
    OR EanCode = '00'+@ean 
    OR EanCode = '000'+@ean 
    OR EanCode = '0000'+@ean 
    OR EanCode = '00000'+@ean 
    OR EanCode = '000000'+@ean
```

with `@ean` being the string parameter of course

It seemed counter-intuitive at first but it is indeed the fastest way.

Answer (score 3):

You should take the time to fix the table. One method is to change the EANs to the appropriate form. If you want a string of a fixed length, then do something like:

```
select distinct right(replicate('0', 13) + ean, 13) as ean, productid
into #temptable;

truncate table eantbl;

insert into eantbl(ean, productid)
    select ean, productid
    from #temptable;
```

That may not be feasible, if you need the improper EAN values for some reason.

An alternative is to put a canonical form into the table. Something like:

```
alter table eantbl add CanonicalEAN char(13);

update eantbl
    set CanonicalEAN = right(replicate('0', 13) + ean, 13);

create index idx_eantbl_canonicalean on eantbl(CanonicalEAN);
```

Then you can do the comparison using the appropriate column and take advantage of an index.

Answer (score 1):

Add a computed column that would trim and otherwise normalize the EAN:

```
alter table EanTbl add NormalizedEan as (dbo.NormalizeEan([Ean]));
```

Next, add an index for this column and you'll be off to the races.

Comment: Although I like this Approach, unfortunately it is not really an Option. The index Needs to stay on that column and there is not enough free disk space to Cluster another index on the computed column. :(

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to first cast them to an `int` to remove the leading zeros and checking against that field before inserting.

```
CAST(CAST([EAN] AS INT) AS VARCHAR(13)) AS [EANfixed]
```

I'm mostly guessing the code here, since I don't really know what your tables and fields look like.